# css animation not work. is there a problem with my code

Tags: css, reactjs

its is very simple problem

so i just copied css from https://github.com/jh3y/whirl/blob/dist/css/building-blocks.css that give loading animation in css and i want it to apply it to my react project

I'm sure I included correctly, but it still doesn't work. and i am just doing like this
`<div className="building-blocks" />`

but its not working. is there any problem with the css code or can you show me how to do it correctly

Comment: Read up about keyframes and how to use them in CSS animation. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Answer (score 0):

its not the classname, it should be animation name, you can name your div class whatever you want!

```
.building-blocks {
  animation: building-blocks;
}
```